# Default function parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible to set default parameter values for functions in JavaScript like with PHP?

```
function phpFunc($param='defvalue'){
    echo $param;
}

phpFunc();
```

Would result in 'defvalue' being outputted...

Is this possible in javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You would have to do something like this :

```
function jsFunc(param) {
  param = typeof param == 'undefined' ? 'defvalue' : param;
  return param;
}

alert( jsFunc() );               // shows defvalue
alert( jsFunc('Hello, world!');  // shows Hello, world!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: excellent! i was thinking about using a lack of passed param as a default value. thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

Or just:

```
function jsFunc(param){
     param = param || defValue;
     return param;
 }
```